# Android : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x324b3944 in tid 2055 (IntentService[u)

Tags: android, file-upload, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to record audio and upload a file to a server, but in **Samsung SM-G900W8 (Android 6.0.1, API 23)**  my app crashing

**Here is my crash logs:**

```
    11-22 19:00:53.860 826-2055/com.app.posterity E/log_tag: imagePath2:
11-22 19:00:53.870 826-2055/com.app.posterity A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x324b3944 in tid 2055 (IntentService[u)
11-22 19:00:53.930 325-325/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/kltevl/kltecan:6.0.1/MMB29M/G900W8VLU1DQB2:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '14'
    ABI: 'arm'
    pid: 826, tid: 2055, name: IntentService[u  >>> com.app.posterity <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x324b3944
```

**Here is my code for file uploading**

- Api code using retrofit

  ```
  final File file = new File(outputFile);
  ProgressRequestBody fileBody = new ProgressRequestBody(file, new 
  ProgressRequestBody.UploadCallbacks() {
  public long oldUplod = 0;
      @Override
      public void onProgressUpdate(int percentage) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onProgressByte(long uploaded, long total) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onError() {
      }

      @Override
      public void onFinish() {

      }
  });

  Call<UploadVideoResponse> call;
  MultipartBody.Part body = null;
  List<MultipartBody.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
  body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", "Test", fileBody);
  parts.add(body);

  String authentication_token = Pref.getValue(RecordAudioAnswerActivity.this, PrefKey.AUTHTOKEN, "");
  call = ApiClient.getClientUpload().question_edit(parts, authentication_token, question_id, question, "false");

  call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadVideoResponse>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<UploadVideoResponse> call, Response<UploadVideoResponse> response) {


          Log.i("Response:1-", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

          Toast.makeText(RecordAudioAnswerActivity.this, "onResponse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          if (response.isSuccessful()) {
              UploadVideoResponse commonResponse = response.body();


          } else {
              LogM.e("errrrrrr" + "errr");
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<UploadVideoResponse> call, Throwable t) {
          LogM.e("errrrrrr" + t.toString());

      }
  });
  ```

Here is my gradle code

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.posterity"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
        /*ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi','x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            //abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }*/
        ndk {
           // abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            abiFilters "armeabi","armeabi-v7a","x86","x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation project(':scissors')
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
    implementation 'net.gotev:speech:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.xeoh.android:text-highlighter:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile project(path: ':camerakit')
    compile project(path: ':ffmpeg4android_lib')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I debug the code execution going perfectly to this line

```
call = ApiClient.getClientUpload().question_edit(parts, authentication_token, question_id, question, "false");
```

then is shows below error

```
SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT)
```

then app crash then I show error in the log file which I mentioned. I also check file size, variable detail etc which is alright.

> Note : I used FFMPEG "ffmpeg4android" version is  "322.00.02_LM322"

```
compile project(path: ':ffmpeg4android_lib')
```

> This error is accue in specific devices like Samsung SM-G900W8 and Nexus 5

not understand what is an actual problem in this please help me out from this it will save my days.

Comment: what is your android target level? 23+ ?

Comment: Starting with API 23, shared objects must not contain text relocations. Double check your ffmpeg lib has not `TEXTREL` entry or the `TEXTREL` flag.

Comment: android target level is 19 minumum and maximum 27

Comment: i add gradle code

Comment: your `targetSdkVersion` is 27, maybe just try to low it down to 22 to see if the issue disappear.

Comment: @AD10 Have you resolved this issue ? I am stuck in the same bug

Comment: Not exactly but first check file is not empty , if file is blank it will be crashed